# Control UWP app with Xamarin (Android)

Tags: c#, networking, xamarin, raspberry-pi, uwp

I will create an app for my Raspberry in UWP (Windows 10 IOT) to display a webView (like Youtube).
And, with this app, I want to create a Xamarin Application for my Android to control/manage my UWP App.

I just to know if it's possible (without webservice) to connect my Android App to my UWP app in direct connection (LAN Connection) (IP to IP).

I want, for example, when I clic on my android app on the youtube button, send "http://youtube.com/" to my UWP app.

Thanks for your help

EDIT : I found TCPListener, what do you think ?

Comment: If you just want to send commands, I'd not use something connection based like TCP. A message protocol based on UDP is enough. But why no webservice? It's **alot** easier to implement on both sides!

Comment: So, where can I host my webservice ? On my RPI ?

Comment: yes on your raspberry pi.

Comment: Ok but, if I make a webservice on my rpi and I send a command with my phone. My webservice need to refresh his "get" function every time ? Like Peacecwz project ?

Comment: Maybe I understand your problem wrong. But the described scenario is unidirectional from phone to Pi. Something like POST http://mypi/doSomething

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did same as this app but i used service. You can send data on TCP Socket. I will make a sample app with sending command on socket.

If you want to look my repo. It's [here](https://github.com/peacecwz/RemoteTV)

Comment: Hey, really thank you, I'm gonna take a look
EDIT : Ok, as I can see, you use timer to request your url. But I don't want timer, and this is why I want to use TCP for command. I just don't want to have "delay" with Timer ^^

Comment: I will make a sample with Socket and i'll add here github repo